# How do I delete a file I own for just me?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-shared-folder

On Google Drive, I own several big files that are in someone else's shared folder. I want the collaborators to still have the files but I want my storage space back. The options for each member of the list of collaborators under advanced sharing options never shows the change owner option. I assume if I delete the files and remove them from my trash to reclaim the storage, they will be deleted for everyone. How can I work around these hurdles to delete these files from my Drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ownership of files only could be transferred for Google own file formats. The ownership of files on other formats like images, videos, PDF, etc. can't be transferred. The alternative is that another user make a copy of those files and share them with the other users.

If your files are on Google file formats, first you have to share those files with an specific user, then you could transfer the ownership of that file to that user. For further details see [Change your sharing settings](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494893?hl=en).